# Python thread pool, only spawn after previous threads have stopped

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have an iterator that reads a file and I have a ThreadPool (8 threads) that processes this `iterator` with `pool.apply_async`.  The problem I have with this is the iterator has the potential of reading very large files and I don't want to load the entire file into memory at once.  I know iterators don't load keep the data in memory but only returns data when `next` is called.

The problem that I have is when I `pool.apply_async` the iterator is read through to the end creating threads.  The pool only allows 8 threads to run at a time but my entire file is now in memory.

What I'm looking for is a pool that will only create 8 thread, start those threads and when one thread has finished create another thread with the `iterator.next` data.  This way I don't have to keep the entire file in memory, I can grab data when a thread is ready to process it.

Hope that makes sense.  I'll try and put some code up soon.

Using python 2.7

Comment: which version of python?  3.2+ has `concurrent.futures` which has the features you're looking for.

Comment: @roippi I'm using python 2.7.  Thanks though I'll look into that.

Comment: There is a backport of concurrent.futures to python 2.7. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures

Comment: If the file is on disk, then is it that hard to ensure that each thread releases memory as it goes? Similarly can't you `seek` to the point in the file the thread is working on, or does that actually read the whole thing into memory? Have you actually experienced a problem with running out of memory or just worried it might happen?